# Does tmpfs automatically resize when the amount RAM changes

Tags: filesystems, mount, tmp, tmpfs

If I have a tmpfs set to 50%, and later on I add or remove RAM, does tmpfs automatically adjust its partition size?

Also what if I have multiple tmpfs each set at 50%. Do multiple tmpfs compete against each other for the same 50%? How is this managed by the OS?

Comment: This _might_ be better off over at SuperUser

Comment: I've seen somewhat similar questions over here.

Comment: Asked here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134762/does-tmpfs-automatically-resize-when-the-amount-ram-changes-and-does-it-compete